# Nested virtual directory or application within sitecore site, is it possible 

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, sitecore

I would like to nest asp.net web app within sitecore site, something like this:

```
<sitecore web root folder>
   .
         <virtual directory/app folder>
```

I want to access sitecore site by using following url:

```
http://<whatever site name>
```

and I would like to access web app by using following url:

```
 http://<whatever site name>/<whatever virtual directory/app alias>
```

Is this possible?

I tried it but when I try to access my web app (not sitecore) then web app complains about missing sitecore.
I believe that is because now I have two config files ans when accessing web app iis/asp.net processing first sitecore web.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, your assumption is correct. See [Creating a project in a virtual directory under Sitecore root](http://sdn.sitecore.net/FAQ/Administration/Project%20in%20Virtual%20Directory.aspx) article for more information about this kind of setup.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a virtual app under a Sitecore root path. Because its an app it will use its own app pool and you can have a web.config for it. I guess the physical files will be OUTSIDE of the Sitecore Website folder but the from a URL you can make the virtual app located anywhere below the Sitecore root.

Comment: Hi Mark, I tried having physical files outside of sitecore root folder and it didn't work anyway...

Comment: Are these files for a completely separate app? Did you use virtual directory or virtual app? What error did you get?

Comment: Yes, files are for calendar control that is being used within sitecore. I tried both, virtual directory and app and with app system complains about missing sitecore dll (naturally), with virtual directory system got stuck at processing sitecore root web config file.