# Sitecore and Non-Sitecore Sites on the Same Domain

Tags: iis, dns, sitecore, sitecore6

We're currently running Sitecore 6.0.0 (090120). Before you ask the obvious question, I've only been with the company less than four months, so I don't have an answer. I've got a part of the site that I want to pull out into its own subdomain. The new site will be an independent dynamic site (most likely ASP.NET MVC) created outside of Sitecore (not using any Sitecore resources), and its content will **not** be housed in Sitecore. I want to do this so that the new site can have a URL like *newsite.mycompany.com*, on the same domain as the Sitecore solution, but not part of the Sitecore solution. I proposed setting up the subdomain and using a virtual directory in IIS 6 to house the new site, but I was told that Sitecore won't allow this type of configuration.

Can anyone shed a little light on this subject? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the new site has nothing to do with Sitecore at all, then just set up a whole new site in IIS and bind it to your subdomain.

Even if the Sitecore site is bound to the default website, by creating a new site you can instruct IIS to route traffic on "newsite.mycompany.com" to your new site. In IIS6, you set this in the "Host header for this Web Site" field in the new site wizard. If the site exists, bring up the properties for the web site, on the "web site" tab click "advanced" and add the subdmoain in the "Multiple identities for this Web site"

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, you want to run a (static) website on your domain and a sitecore site in a virtual directory?
It is possible, with some modifications to the config, see: [Nested virtual directory or application within sitecore site, is it possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795022/nested-virtual-directory-or-application-within-sitecore-site-is-it-possible)

Comment: So you want to run Sitecore on the domain and your other site (maybe MVC) on the virtual directory. I don't see why that wouldn't work (except for maybe MVC not supporting virtual dirs, don't know that) as long as you add your virtual dir to the IgnoreUrlPrefixes setting in Sitecore's web.config. That will tell Sitecore to ignore that dir and everything in it and not process it.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore will definitely allow this, you have been misinformed.  What is NOT explicitly supported is Sitecore itself running out of a virtual directory.  However, the scenario you are describing does not require a virtual directory at all.  Why use one?  I advise avoiding this wherever possible, as it's just an added complication.

Comment: I figured as much...I'm open to suggestions, if you have any.